# Flutter LongPressDraggable won't allow dropping before moving

Tags: flutter

I have a `LongPressDraggable` widget. When drag starts after a long press, the `onDragStarted` function is called in which I show an overlay over the LongPressDraggable with some DragTargets inside.

```dart
 LongPressDraggable(
    data: someData,
    feedback: someFeedback,
    onDragStarted: () {
      addOverlay(); // shown on the top of the draggable
    },
    onDragEnd: (d) {
      removeOverlay();

    },
    child: someChild,
 );
```

When I long press the function `onDragStarted` is called. However the dragging is not really starting until we move the cursor/finger. That means we can't drop until we move.

I need the dragging to start immediately so that it can be dropped and captured on the overlay that I'm showing, even before moving.

Is there a way to start the dragging on long press without moving so that it can be dropped immediately?

Comment: My `onDragEnd` is never fired at all!... No matter WHAT I do. I just can't get that function to run! Does yours run, at least after you've dragged some distance?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Yes, it does work. Have you tried with the example provided in the docs? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html

Comment: I didn't... I tried this example: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget but it doesn't have an `onDragEnd`.  I might check out that other one, but as for now, I'm worked around it with an `onAccept`, an `onDragCompleted` and an `onDraggableCanceled`. At least one of them is always fired, sometimes two.